# How to measure the execution time of every block when using CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu, parallel-processing

clock() is not accurate enough.

Comment: I believe he means a Thread Block, a terminology used by CUDA.

Comment: I mean that every block is assigned different part of a whole compuatation.I want to test accruate time every block use to finish its own task.

Comment: I've been using clock() but didn't notice how inaccurate it was. Can you tell me? I think it was accurate because it invokes the clock performance counters inside GPU.

Comment: @cnhk Can you please provide additional information in your question so that the question is a useful reference for other stackoverflow users. The clock() device function is cycle accurate so it is unclear why you believe it is not accurate. Reasons for inaccuracy could include incorrect use of clock(), failure to handle rollover, compiler moving the SASS instruction, etc.

Answer (score 13):

Use CUDA events for measure time of kernels or CUDA operations (memcpy etc):

```
// Prepare
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
// Start record
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
// Do something on GPU
MyKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(input_data, output_data);
// Stop event
cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
float elapsedTime;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop); // that's our time!
// Clean up:
cudaEventDestroy(start);
cudaEventDestroy(stop);
```

See CUDA Programming Guide, section 3.2.7.6

Comment: This gives the total execution time of the whole kernel, not for individual blocks I think.

Comment: Of course. Scheduler executes blocks in random order, number of blocks is big (you must have memory to store all timers), and the main thing: what time you exactly want to measure? Most of the time blocks spend in sleep, waiting for memory, due to RAM latency. But thanks to high loading of GPU, while one block is waiting, another one is running. So execution time of specific block can be very big. I think that mean time is the most important characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

How about using clock() function in every CUDA thread to calculate start and end times. And store it in a array such a way that you can figure out which thread start/stop at which time based on array indices like following:

```
__global__ void kclock(unsigned int *ts) {
    unsigned int start_time = 0, stop_time = 0;

    start_time = clock();

    // Code we need to measure should go here.

    stop_time = clock();

    ts[(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) * 2] = start_time;
    ts[(blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) * 2 + 1] = stop_time; 
}
```

Then use this array to figure out minimal start time and maximum stop time for block you are considering. For example you can calculate range of indices of time array which corresponds to the (0, 0) block in CUDA and use min/max to calculate the execution time.

Comment: In order to reduce memory consumption and I would recommend adding conditional logic at the start of the warp to only have threadIdx.x == 0 (assuming 1D blockDim) to read and write the timestamp. At the end of the kernel I would recommend having laneIdx == 0 of each warp write the stop time to the same memory location. This will be a race condition but will be fairly accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I think long long int clock64() is what you are looking for?

See Cuda Programming Guide, C Language Extensions, B. 11.